# MVC Form based Spring Security login?

Tags: security, spring, model-view-controller, authentication

I have an application that uses Spring Security to control access to pages, to manage user roles (`GrantedAuthority`) and for ACL. The application uses the standard `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` that intercepts requests to `/j_spring_security_check` (with `j_username` and `j_password` request parameters),  and using a `ProviderManager` it authenticates the user and on success stores it in the `SecurityContextHolder`.

The above is configured in the security context, using a customized `UserDetailsService`:

```
<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider user-service-ref='myUserDetailsService'/>
</authentication-manager>
```

The above approach in my case is not optimal, for the following reasons:

- Adding a captcha requires extra filters
- In order to customize the login logic, I need to replace the `AuthenticationProvider` as well
- showing errors in the login form is complex, since I cannot use Spring MVC's forms

My idea is to remove the interceptor based login and put all the logic inside a Spring 3 MVC controller. The pseudo-code is as following:

```
RequestMapping(value="/login/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String attemptLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
    @ModelAttribute("login") LoginCmd login, Model model) {

    // validate command (username, password, captcha)
    // ...

    // load user from DB
    User user = userService.loadUserByUsername(login.getUsername());

    // extra logic (check number of failed logins + other stuff)
    // ...

    // In case everything is fine, create a spring security User

    /* Instead of creating the user, read it from DB */
    org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User authUser =
        new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
        login.getUsername() /*username*/,
        login.getPassword() /*password*/,
        true /*enabled*/,
        true /*accountNonExpired */,
        true /*credentialsNonExpired */,
        true /*accountNonLocked*/,
        new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>() /*authorities*/
    );

    // build the AuthenticationToken
    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authResult =
        new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(authUser, login.getPassword(),
        authUser.getAuthorities());
    // use WebAuthenticationDetailsSource do build details
    authResult.setDetails(detailsSource.buildDetails(request));
    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);

    return SUCCESS_VIEW;
}
```

Do you see any problem with the solution here above? Is setting the authentication inside the `SecurityContextHolder` enough? Am I missing something?

Comments and suggestions are welcome ;-)
Thanks a lot to everyone
Andrea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went through the Spring Security code, and on successful authentication also the original code just stores the `Authentication` object in the SecurityContextHolder, nothing else is done.

For example, in class `AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter` (which is used by the *standard* login intercepting requests to `/j_spring_security_check`) does that:

```
 protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {

    if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
        logger.debug("Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: " + authResult);
    }

    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authResult);

    rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, authResult);

    // Fire event
    if (this.eventPublisher != null) {
        eventPublisher.publishEvent(new InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent(authResult, this.getClass()));
    }

    successHandler.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authResult);
}
```

I implemented this on my application and everything works fine.